# React input elements all re-render when onChange is called on a single input, even with memo on the input and useCallback on the onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, rendering, memoization

```js
const { useReducer } = React

const InputWithLabelAbove = ({
  labelText,
  id,
  onChange,
  pattern,
  value,
}) => {
  return (
    <label htmlFor={id}>
      {labelText}
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          id={id}
          pattern={pattern}
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </div>
    </label>
  )
}

const MemoInputWithLabelAbove = React.memo(InputWithLabelAbove)

const Component = () => {
  // calc object
  const calculatorObj = {
    tax: '',
    water: '',
    energy: '',
    internet: '',
    transport: '',
    food: '',
    education: '',
    childcare: '',
    otherInsurance: '',
    otherCosts: ''
  }

  // state
  const inputValues = {
    total: '',
    showCalculator: false,
    calculatedTotal: 0,
    calc: {
      ...calculatorObj
    }
  }

  // reducer for form states
  const [values, setValues] = useReducer(
    (state, newState) => ({...state, ...newState}), 
    inputValues
  )
  
    // on change function to handle field states.
  const handleChange = React.useCallback((e, type) => {
    const { value, id } = e.target

console.log('onchange')

    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/
    const converted = !re.test(value) || value.length === 0 ? '' : parseInt(value, 10)

    if (type === 'calculator') {
      const obj = {
        ...values.calc,
        [id]: converted
      }
      setValues({ calc: { ...obj }})
    }
  }, [values.calc])
  
  const calcLabelArr = ['Council tax', 'Water', 'Energy (gas and/or electricity)', 'Internet', 'Transport', 'Food', 'Children\'s education', 'Childcare', 'Other insurance', 'Other essential costs']
  
  
  return (
    <div
      style={{ width: '60%', marginBottom: '20px', position: 'relative' }}
    >
      { Object.entries(values.calc).map((i, index) => {
      return <div key={calcLabelArr[index]}>
        <MemoInputWithLabelAbove 
          id={i[0]}
          type="text"
          labelText={calcLabelArr[index]}
          onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'calculator')}
          value={i[1]}
        />
      </div>
      }
    )}
      </div>
  )
  
  }
  
   ReactDOM.render(
    <Component />,
    document.getElementById('reactBind')
    )
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="reactBind"></div>
```

Below is the rendering of the inputs using an array (with 10 elements) so 10 input elements are rendered.

```
 // calculator object typically populated but for this example its empty for ease.
  const calcLabelArr = []

  // function to return calculator fields
  const buildView = () => {
    return (
      <Col
        xs="12"
        md={{ span: 6, offset: 3 }}
        style={{ marginBottom: '20px', position: 'relative' }}
      >
      { Object.entries(values.calc).map((i, index) => {
        return <div key={calcLabelArr[index]}>
          <InputWithLabelAbove 
            id={i[0]}
            type="text"
            labelPosition="top"
            labelText={calcLabelArr[index]}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'calculator')}
            value={i[1]}
          />
        </div>
      }
      )}
      </Col>
    )
  }
```

Below is the onChange function used to set that state of each input.

```
const handleChange = React.useCallback((e, type) => {
    const { value, id } = e.target

    const re = /^[0-9\b]+$/
    const converted = !re.test(value) || isEmpty(value) ? '' : parseInt(value, 10)

    if (type === 'calculator') {
      const obj = {
        ...values.calc,
        [id]: converted
      }
      setValues({ calc: { ...obj }})
    } else {
      setValues({
        total: converted,
      })
    }
  }, [values.calc])
```

Below is the component that is memoized.

```
import React from 'react'
import { join } from 'lodash'
import { Label, StyledInput, Red } from './style'

export type IProps = {
  labelPosition: string,
  labelText: string,
  id: string,
  hasErrored?: boolean,
  onChange: () => void,
  dataUxId?: string,
  pattern?: string,
  sessioncamHide?: boolean,
  sessioncamClassList?: string | string[],
  value?: string,
  validation?: boolean,
}

const InputWithLabelAbove: React.FC<IProps> = ({
  labelPosition,
  labelText,
  id,
  hasErrored,
  onChange,
  dataUxId,
  pattern,
  sessioncamHide,
  sessioncamClassList,
  value,
  validation,
}) =>
  (
    <Label hasErrored={hasErrored} labelPosition={labelPosition} htmlFor={id}>
      {labelText && (<span>{labelText}{validation && (<Red>*</Red>)}</span>)}
      <div>
        <StyledInput
          type="text"
          id={id}
          hasErrored={hasErrored}
          dataUxId={`InputText_${dataUxId}`}
          pattern={pattern}
          labelPosition={labelPosition}
          value={value}
          onInput={onChange}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
      </div>
    </Label>
  )

export const MemoInputWithLabelAbove = React.memo(InputWithLabelAbove)
```

As you can see, it isn't the key I don't think that is causing the re-render, my input component is memoized and the onChange is using a callback, however on using the react profiler, every onChange re-renders all my input components. Could someone elaborate to why this is?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (the above is close, but we need to see how the input component is memoized and such), ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). A runnable example helps you make sure the question has all the information it needs to be answered, and helps people answering ensure their answers are complete as well.

Comment: Again, please provide a **runnable** MRE.

Comment: I have done it, apologies I haven't had much experience with stack overflow so was getting use to it. Please see snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that jumps out is this property on the input component:

```
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, 'calculator')}
```

Even though `handleChange` is memoized, you're creating a **new** arrow function every time to call the memoized function. So even if the input is memoized, it's seeing a **new** `onChange` every time.

You'd need to pass a stable function to avoid re-rendering, for instance:

```
const onChange = React.useCallback(
    e => handleChange(e, "calculator"),
    [handleChange]
);
```

and then

```
onChange={onChange}
```

*(It wasn't clear to me where you're defining `handleChange`; if it's within the component that's rendering these inputs, you can probably combine that definition with the above in a single `useCallback` or possible `useMemo` if it's multiple callbacks. Although small pieces are good too.)*

Comment: *(Oops, missed out the dependency in `useCallback`; hit refresh if you don't see it.)*

Comment: thanks for your answer, I have given this a go and it seems to still re-render all the inputs. Unsure to why this still doesn't work. :/

Comment: updated to show the React typescript component using Memo.